# assistance in refining .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working to refine code within an `.htaccess` file but am having problems with rewriting the url for sub directory requests from `https` to `http`.  Here's my attempt:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^dashboard(/.*)?$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^dashboard(/.*)?$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This code works well for `https` requests to the root url, but when a request comes in for, say, https://example.com/sub the url is left alone and an invalid cert warning is displayed.

My intention is to rewrite all requests except those for the `dashboard` subdirectory.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put dashboard clause in RewriteCond:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|jpe?g|png|bmp|gif)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !>dashboard [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Attempted, https://example.com/sub still does not rewrite to http://example.com/sub :(  I'm curious what the purpose of moving the dashboard clause into a RewriteCond is?

Comment: Okay, have you tried to use %{HTTPS} =on instead of server port? And what module do you use to server https connections, mod_ssl?

Comment: %{HTTPS}=on acted the same as %{SERVER_PORT} =443.  I'm fairly certain that mod_ssl is the module used to serve https connections.

Comment: Have you tried too look at mod_rewrite debug output? RewriteLogLevel 9, RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"?